# Why can't I access this url from AWS, but I can from my local machine?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, web-scraping

Here's `test.rb`.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
puts open('https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/cc/CorporationsCanada/fdrlCrpDtls.html?corpId=1056565').read
```

When I run this code from my local machine, I successfully open and read the page, printing its contents.

But when I run it from my AWS box with the command `ruby test.rb`, I get a 503 error. This has only happened in the past week. Before this, I could open pages on the website without problem.

My local machine runs Windows 7. My AWS box runs Linux.

What's going on here?

Comment: @JesseSielaff Updated my question. Same result: Successful on Win7 local machine, 503 error on AWS Linux box.

Comment: Thanks. This may mean a problem with the AWS, but if it is, I don't know how I would check it...

Comment: Hm, then I wonder how do even diagnose the problem, since I could successfully run `test.rb` from my AWS box up til yesterday...

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that `www.ic.gc.ca` has something configured that is disallowing access from AWS. Based on the fact that your scraper was working until recently, it may even be that they detected they were being scraped and set up a rule to keep you out, hitting all of AWS by mistake.

Comment: If that is the case, is there anyway to set up my scraper so it doesn't look like it's  AWS?

Comment: AWS IP or IP range could be banned. You could try to get new IP and try scraping then

Comment: ...or... don't run a scraper against a site that may very well be blocking you because you are scraping them, if that's what you're doing.